# How do I compose an enum from another enum in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have an enum containing some arbitrary values and want to automatically map the values of the enum to another enum 1-to-1 (with some arbitrary addition). What would be the most idiomatic way to accomplish this task?

I want to do something like add `Element.keys+"Magic"` to the Skills enum in a declarative fashion and then have these values available as keys without needing to duplicate the work and add a suffix.

```
enum Element {
  Air,
  Fire,
  Earth,
  Water
}
```

-->

```
enum Skills {
  // Unrelated Skills
  Unarmed,
  LightArmor,
  etc. . .

  // 1-to-1 Mapping
  AirMagic,
  FireMagic,
  EarthMagic,
  WaterMagic
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extending Enum in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52857698/extending-enum-in-typescript)

Comment: @Blackhole Unfortunately no. Essentially what I'm attempting to do here is establish a single enum and then compose new enums by iterating over the original enum keys. It's not so much a union of enum types as it is a way to reduce duplication.

Comment: What value should `Skills.AirMagic` have?

Comment: @jcalz Because this is an integer enum, the value of `Skills.AirMagic` would be equal to its integer position in the skills enum at the location the declaration was provided. 

So if the declarative value was provided after `Unarmed` and `LightArmor` the position of `AirMagic` would be '2' and `FireMagic` would be '3', etc. . .

Comment: Okay, thanks.  Well, enums don't compose.  You could write your own helper function to produce enum-like objects, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mLy02W).  Please check that against your use cases to see if it works for you.  If so I could write up an answer explaining it; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for this! The more I read the more the more it seems I can't utilize enums to accomplish my design goal.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you're asking to compose and extend `enum` with each other, like extending and composing their inner members, at compile time and with simple set operations.

Shortly: *you can't*.

Since enums are defined at compile time, their set of member is static and can't be derived from other enums. You *can* have [computed members](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#computed-and-constant-members), but that's for *the value they hold in*.

For you to access the `enum` and manipulate like you've asked in the question, you'd need access to metaprogramming onto your enums, i.e. using decorators onto them. But that's [currently not possible](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3279) in Typescript.

My advice would be to use a `class` and / or a `type`. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52197931/how-to-use-decorators-on-enum-in-typescript) for more.

Answer (score 1):

*Answering my own question in case others are looking to accomplish something similar. . .*

---

While it doesn't seem to be possible to accomplish this task with enums, I have managed something in the same spirit with 'Template Literal Types'.

```
type Element =
  | "Air"
  | "Fire"
  | "Earth"
  | "Water";
```

```
type Skills =
  | "Unarmed"
  | "LightArmor"
  | `${Element}Magic`;
```

This yields a string union type like so: `"Unarmed" | "LightArmor" | "AirMagic" | "FireMagic" | "EarthMagic" | "WaterMagic"`

---

**Resources**

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogNhAthAdsAKuaBeKAiAQQEsAnPKAH3wDFSJyq8YBDE4ACwfwHVngIyAbgCwAKDGhIUAMoBrInDgBnKLjwBVFK2QATLngAyRAObtgBEogD2ZSlAAGAEgDe8JKgxYAvgFlmxogBjexFxUQAzAFcUQOAiKxQofiVgAAoleUUALhlM5QBKKGcxKChAhKUrBAA6OCtjdLz8sS8xMQB6dqhMKWYoFJIiFGModgFocJsoZkjgK3LEMAQ4hOqJCBTUwlI-AMC8ZrCgA

Comment: The code [shown here](https://tsplay.dev/mLy02W) is more similar to your original than using a union of string literals; should I post it as an answer?

Comment: @jcalz Go for it!